# how to find index of UIButton in array if they are the same value?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, tags

sorry if the title not describe the problem well
i have 4 button with 4 letters ["g","o","o","d"]
it is a game about
if the player can guess the word ,
which is in this case the word is : "good"

i have a hint button that do this :
*give one letter from the four
*hide the button with the given letter
it works very well

but the problem is :
the word "good"
has two "o" letter
so the hint button now well delete two button with the letter "O"

here is what i did so far :

```
//  this method will add a letter from the right word "qlap" to the answer textfield and it work perfectly :
    
let text_ans = ans.text?.count
ans.text! += qlab![text_ans!+0]
    
// the four letters
let buttin = [Letter1,Letter2,Letter3,Letter4]

// check if hint letter above == button title letter
for title in buttin {
    if qlab![text_ans!+0] == title!.title(for: .normal) {
        let tag = title!.tag
        if title?.tag == tag {
            // how can i just hide for once if there is a duplicate
            title?.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

and here is a gif to make it more clear :

[image: see the gif]

i tried do it with the button tags rather than title
but at the end i went to the same result

Comment: After hide you can break the loop if you check your button with title (without tag)

Comment: you can set tag=index of button in array. when you touch the button hide it then add title to input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `first(where:)` (documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/first(where:))) function to find the first button with a `title` that matches what you are looking for *and* where `isHidden == false`.

So something along the lines of:

```
if let hintButton = buttin.first(where: { $0.title(for: .normal) == qlab![text_ans!+0] && !$0.isHidden }) {
    // now you have the first - not hidden - button matching what you are looking for, time to hide it
    hintButton.isHidden = true
}
```

*note:* I haven't checked the above in a compiler so there might be syntax errors which I'm sure the compiler will inform you about in it's friendly manner.

Comment: more than clean ! worked very well , thank you for providing the doc

Comment: Glad to hear so. Good luck :)